# using mingw and g++ compiler

Tags: c++, windows

I’m trying to run my c++ files off the prompt, but nothing is showing, e.g.

```
    C:\C++\mingw>g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

It seems to be bug free but nothing displays, in this case a simple hello to the terminal.

My code is a straightforward

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello \n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just ran `g++` right?
I don't really do much on Windows, but I am guessing (with 98% of confident), you didn't run `hello.exe`. Did you?

Comment: um no, and yes that worked, good call my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the simplest answer "Just run `hello.exe`" is correct. Here's some additional logic behind:

If you're used to *interpreted* languages, such as Python or Lua, you might have noticed that you execute them by supplying source file to the executable, as such:

```
python my_source.py
```

However, this works because each time you run `python` command, it reads the source file given, and then interprets it and executes appropriate machine instructions based on the file contents - it *interprets* the file.

C++, on the other hand, is a *compiled* language. The execution of `g++`, which is a *compiler*, generates said machine code for your platform, and stops there. Next time you don't need the compiler to run your program; every instruction is encoded as the machine code in the `.exe` file. That's why you can share your `.exe` file with your friend if he doesn't have a compiler, but he won't be able to execute python script without python environment installed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this depends on the implementation. There exist implementations that compile Python (Java, Ruby...) to machine code, and there exist C++ interpreters. What you say is however true for the most used implementations (e.g. g++ is a C++ compiler).

Comment: @Claudio I didn't want to complicate it even more. The *most-used* is probably enough in the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe // This command only produce the exe file
```

The executive file doesn't run automatically. You should run it by yourself.

```
hello.exe
```